# How to add a Button with context menu on my app title bar on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I noticed that some applications based on Qt have a button with a context menu in their title bar, I would like to achieve a similar effect in my application, can someone tell me how to achieve it? The image shows one of those applications with the  button clicked showing the context menu
Button with Context Menu

[image]
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title bar is generally handled by the window manager ([DWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager) on Windows or [KWin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KWin) for KDE on Linux, etc.).

There are only a limited things you can do to customize the native title bar, and it will not be portable.

What you can do is disable the native title bar by using [`Qt::WindowTitleHint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) or [`Qt::FramelessWindowHint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) and implements your own title bar within your software. But this has some drawbacks as you lose some of the features provided by the window manager.

You can start by looking at these forum posts:

- [Customize Titlebar on forum.qt.io](https://forum.qt.io/topic/46620/customize-titlebar)
- [Customize window frame on forum.qt.io](https://forum.qt.io/topic/26108/customize-window-frame)

Comment: Explorer is not the window manager on Windows. The window manager in Windows is called Window Manager.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option:
if You use QML you can create your custom window title bar by setting Qt.FramelessWindowHint. Then inside create your own titlebar Rectangle with everything that you want

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
}
```

But unfortunately you will need to write all windows controls (moving, sizing, buttons ...) from scratch
([here is some info about moving](https://forum.qt.io/topic/7127/how-to-implement-custom-titlebar/4))